# How to create a list of duplicated arrays in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a list of repeated entries for an arbitrary number of times. For example, I want to have `list(c(1.0,1.0),c(1.0,1.0),c(1.0,1.0))` but bigger.

I tried `rep(c(1.0,1.0),3)` and that doesn't work because it outputs `[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`.

My goal is to get something of the form

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 1

[[3]]
[1] 1 1.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
rep(list(c(1.0,1.0)),3)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 1

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 1
```

Or

```
replicate(3, c(1,1), simplify=FALSE)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 1

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 1
```

Or

```
l1 <- vector('list', 3)
l1[seq_along(l1)] <- list(c(1,1))
```